# Bundle Install Fails on Curb Gem - Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, osx-mountain-lion, curb

When I try to run `bundle install`this is the issue I am running into:

```
Installing curb (0.8.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for curl-config... yes
checking for curlinfo_redirect_time... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
    --with-curl-dir
    --without-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
/Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:443:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:491:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:52:in `block in have_constant'
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from extconf.rb:44:in `have_constant'
    from extconf.rb:62:in `<main>'
```

I am running `ruby 1.9.3p125` with RVM and have re-installed curl (locally) and still am running into the same issue... I have tried everything that I have found on fixing this issue, but can't seem to get the problem to subside. Any one else run across this issue and have successfully fixed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see this message you need to install the XCode Command Line Tools package:

```
You have to install development tools first.
```

These are available from the [developer download site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Comment: Thank you. I also had to restart the terminal after the installation to make it work.